# Problem with fill between and scale option in tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween, tikzscale

I have a problem when I try to scale my tikzpicture. The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elitsit amet ante
lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesentlectu
tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia
loremsit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \begin{axis}[
            unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
            axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-3, xmax=3,
            ymin=-3, ymax=3,
            xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty
        ]
            \addplot [name path=f, domain=-2.2:2.2, samples=2] {x};
            \addplot [name path=g, domain=-3:3, samples=2, dashed] {x+2};
            \addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=gray] fill between[
                of=g and f,
                soft clip={domain=-3:3}
            ];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

with the plot overlaying the text. If I remove the scale option or the fill between part, all is ok.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Once I add the required libraries etc. this looks like a bug to me that should be reported to the `pgfplots` author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling the `tikzpicture` does do something odd with the bounding it seems, but add the `scale` to the `axis` options instead, and it works perfectly fine. Or (which I think makes more sense, usually), set the `width` of the `axis`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elitsit amet ante
lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesentlectu
tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia
loremsit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        %   scale=0.7, % this works
            width=7cm, % and so does this (but no need for both)
            unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
            axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-3, xmax=3,
            ymin=-3, ymax=3,
            xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty
        ]
            \addplot [name path=f, domain=-2.2:2.2, samples=2] {x};
            \addplot [name path=g, domain=-3:3, samples=2, dashed] {x+2};
            \addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=gray] fill between[
                of=g and f,
                soft clip={domain=-3:3}
            ];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the `width` option is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Emanuele Forgot to mention: Seeing as you don't have any axis labels/ticklabels, you might want to add `scale only axis` as well, otherwise the width of the axis itself is the defined width minus 45pt (see section 4.10.1 *Common scaling options* in the `pgpflots` manual).